# \evensidemargin & \oddsidemargin geometry package

Tags: margins, double-sided

how can I put this length with the `geometry` package?

```
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{92.58438pt}%
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{24.38356pt}%
```

Comment: You don't; `geometry` uses a very different model. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note the `twoside` option and the values in `\geometry` in this MWE.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,
tmargin=90pt,
bmargin=90pt,
lmargin=164.85437pt,
rmargin=96.65355pt
}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}
{\Large 
Test: 

The oddsidemargin  is now =  \the\oddsidemargin 

The evensidemargin is now = \the\evensidemargin \\
  }

\layout
\section*{Lore ipsum}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can this change be achieved in memoir class using golden ratio for page layout instead of specifying specific units ?